# How to generate current UTC year in tt model class file

Tags: c#, datetime, t4

How to generate current UTC year in `tt` model class file in file header section in comments.

I have tried following line of code in tt model to generate year in comment. But it is not working.

```
// Copyright <# DateTime.UtcNow.Year.ToString() #> Company name.
```

Comment: Can you try with `<#=` instead of `<#`?

Comment: See also [Writing a T4 Text Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb126478.aspx) under "Expression control blocks".

Comment: @Corak Yes it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Copyright <#= DateTime.UtcNow.Year.ToString() #> Company name.
```

Adding `<#=` instead of `<#` worked for me.